# How can I find the cause of an ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I have a WPF application(.net 4.0) which is working fine on Windows 7 systems. But when I try to run the application windows 8.1 it is working fine for 15 to 20 mins but after that suddenly a popup message is showing like

> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available

popup message showing with two options Debug and close program. When I press debug  it is showing message as FatalExecutionEngineError detected

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x713543ed, on thread 0x23624. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

if i press continue further showing message as

***An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll***

But i didn't get the exact reason why it is failing and which portion of code is causing the problem?

After searching over the net i have tried the following

Added DispatcherUnhandledException handler and App domain Unhandled exception handler and also added legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy to . But nothing is works for me still facing the crash on Windows 8.1

Can someone point me how to detect the code portion which causing the crash? and How to handle FatalExecutionEngineEror exception?

**EDIT**

CLR version Used in both windows 7 and 8.1 is 4.0.30319

Comment: Are you using unsafe code, COM-interop or PInvoke (explicitly)? And what .NET version is installed on the windows 7 systems, and which .NET version is installed on the windows 8.1 system?

Comment: Using .net 4.0 in both windows 7 and 8.1

Comment: Just to make it absolutely clear and unambiguous could you add to the question the exact version numbers of the .NET frameworks that you have installed on the windows 7 system? And then put the same information for the Windows 8.1 system. (I was tech support once, some traits I picked up from that stint stick.)

Comment: You cannot get help with this problem here, you'll need to call Microsoft Support.  Be sure to have a minidump available of the crashed process, they will need it to diagnose the cause.

Comment: I get this exception when using Xceed.AvalonDock  and trying to inspect the visual tree with snoop.

Comment: Got the same exception, when manipulate web browser control using COM interop